# Simple pivot table display in c++? (not full pivot table feature)

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am writing a program making the inventory of the computers of a school.

I have a class `Equip` with 2 string as variable members `m_owner` and `m_type`.

I have a `vector<Equip> v` filled with a bunch of objects Equip.

I am using a **csv** file as argument to my program to fill the vector.

Say `v` contains 5 objects :

```
Equip e1("LaboA", "laptop");
Equip e2("LobaA", "server");
Equip e3("HR", "printer");
Equip e4("LobaA", "laptop");
Equip e5("LobaC", "router");
```

I am trying trying to display the content of v in the form of a pivot table like on the following screenshot :

[image]

I have tried the following :

```
void matrix(const vector<Equip>& v)
{
    vector<Equip> tmp = v;
    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    vector<Equip>::iterator it = unique(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), SameOwner()); 
    tmp.resize(std::distance(tmp.begin(), it));

    for(auto i = tmp.begin(); i != tmp.end(); ++i)
    {
        int j = count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), IsPrinter());
        cout << i->getOwner() << " : " << j << endl;
    }
}
```

I have all the methods written so the code compiles and executes but it does not do what I want.

I understand why but I don't understand how to get this right.

Can you guys give me hints on how to achieve that please? I am at a loss here.

Thank you,

J.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you cout ':'? your image does not have ':'

Comment: That last cout line is just a test print. This is when I realized my approach was wrong.

Comment: create&print a list of distinct owners... (2 nested for loops, or sorting the `v` by `m_owner`) . once you got that similarly create list of `types`  and upgrade your owners print to add search for each type entry (one more nested for) ... and output the count. Lastly add total counts for each type into all this (just single increment).... for big files you should use quick sort and binary search. Also enumeration during the file read (storing just index of owner or type instead strings in the `v`) and adding histogram/counter cross tables can speed/ease up this a lot ...